# Connecting Android with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

i'm having some trouble in connecting my android project to a database at phpmyadmin, can somebody help me how to connect my android project to phpmyadmin?

these are my java codes, it just need to fill the else at the bottom one:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Activity_SignUp extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btnSubmit;
private EditText name;
private EditText uname;
private EditText pass;
private EditText jabatan;
private EditText confirm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    jabatan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Jabatan);
    uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UName);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pass);
    confirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Confirm);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick_SignUp(v);


        }
    });
}

public void onClick_SignUp(View v){

    if (name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "Name Must be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (jabatan.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "Age Must be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (uname.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "UserName must Be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "Password must be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (confirm.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "Confirm Must be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (!confirm.getText().toString().equals(pass.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_SignUp.this, "Confirm Doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

    }
}
}`
```

this is my php file:

Service.php

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','account');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

$Nama = $_POST['Nama'];
$Jabatan = $_POST['Jabatan'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

$sql = "insert into account (Nama,Jabatan,Username,Password) values ('$Nama','$Jabatan','$Username','$Password')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  echo 'success';
}
else{
  echo 'failure';
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

dbConnect.php

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','account');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){


$Nama = $_POST['Nama'];
$Jabatan = $_POST['Jabatan'];
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

if($Nama == '' || $Jabatan == '' || $Username == '' || $Password == ''){

}else{

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE Username='$Username'";

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

if(isset($check)){
echo 'Username already exist';
}else{ 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO account (Nama,Jabatan,Username,Password) VALUES('$Nama','$Jabatan','$Username','$Password')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'successfully registered';
    }else{
        echo 'oops! Please try again!';
    }
}
    mysqli_close($con);
}
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Comment: what are your problem ?

Comment: i don't know how to connect to phpmyadmin, is there a specific code to connect between android studio and phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `v`

```
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick_SignUp();


        }
    });
```

Remove the `v` in `onClick_SignUp` method.

Comment: Please specific your problem

Comment: i don't know how to connect to phpmyadmin, is there a specific code that i need to add my final 'else' statement to connect between android studio and phpmyadmin?

Comment: You need to use third party -pHp

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: You need to write php script

Comment: i already did that too,  all i need is to connect between my android project with the database at phpmyadmin, so at least i can insert a data into the database, i'm making an activity for sign up by the way

Comment: This explain everything. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial-android-login-app-3/

Comment: hold on, i'll add it

Comment: there, i've just add my php file

Comment: create a login function in the else there, and use the code that provided in the link I sent.

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache and MySql are running, you can access it using the ip address. 
Get the Ip of your system running the services and put your android device on the same network then instead of http://localhost/.... Use the ip address
for example http://10.0.2.2/.... in your urls configurations

Comment: do i use "String url" to add the ip address?

Comment: thats the way, how are you adding the ip right now?

Comment: what do you mean?